# PHP compress/zip files with percentage progress bar - is it possible?

Tags: php, zip, compression, progress

Trying to compress bunch of files using ZipArchive class. All is working fine, but I would like to have some kind of status bar with percentage zipped while users are waiting for zipping to be completed.

Is this even possible with ZipArchive? Are there any other zib libraries I could use to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe ZipArchive class? I don't see a ZipLibrary.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using ZipArchive. (http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was look for answer for `extracting` files which `ZipArchive` does not have a callback. The solution I found is looping over the files and creating them individually without using `extractTo` method. I am not sure if it is slower but in my case I have a small number of files and it is extremely fast (milliseconds).

```php
<?php
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open("PATH_TO_ZIP_FILE");

$zip_files_length = $zip->numFiles;

# Create progress logic here

$extract_path = "PATH_TO_DIST";

if ($res === true) {
    for ($index = 0; $index < $zip_files_length; $index++) {
        
        # Add progress advancement here

        // Get file path
        $stat      = $zip->statIndex($index);
        $file_name = $stat['name'];
        $dist      = "{$extract_path}/{$file_name}";

        // Check if the extracted file is a directory (ends with /)
        $is_dir = str_ends_with($file_name, '/');

        if ($is_dir) {
            // Create directory if it does not exist
            if (!is_dir($dist)) {
                mkdir($dist, 0777, true);
            }
            continue;
        }

        // Create file parent directories if they do not exist
        $dir_name = dirname($dist);
        if (!is_dir($dir_name)) {
            mkdir($dir_name, 0777, true);
        }

        // Create file
        $content = $zip->getFromName($file_name);
        file_put_contents("{$extract_path}/{$file_name}", $content);
    }

    $zip->close();
} else {
    throw new \Exception("Failed to extract {$PATH_TO_ZIP_FILE}");
}

# Add progress completion here
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding files to the zip is usually fast. Usually the slowest process if you are zipping large number of files will be the `$zip->close()`. There is a new method in PHP zipArchive class: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.registerprogresscallback.php

This will allow you monitor the progress of zip closing.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open('php.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)) {
    $zip->addFile(PHP_BINARY, 'php');

    $zip->registerProgressCallback(0.05, function ($r) {
        printf("%d%%\n", $r * 100);
    });

    $zip->close();
}
```

This seems to be available in PHP 8.0. I tested this with PHP 7.4+ and is not available there yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just note for who came here hoping to find a way to monitor progress for extractTo: This sadly doesn't work for extractTo as this method not executed on close.